# Adding OSX to a dual boot Windows Linux system for triple boot

Tags: linux, linux-mint, osx, windows, dual-boot

I have a workstation on which I already have installed in a dual boot configuration Windows 10 and Linux Mint Rosa. I have these installed on 2 separate SSDs.

I would like to add a third drive, on which I would like to install OSX, but without reinstalling the other two operating systems.

My hardware configuration is:

CPU: Intel Core i5 6400.

GPU: AMD Radeon R7 370.

RAM: 8GB 2133.

So far, all the documentation I have found for triple booting OSX, Linux and Windows assumes that the system is either a Mac or a hackintosh that has installed on it OSX already.
If anyone could point me into the right direction or give me some tips, I'd greatly appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

More operating systems is not a problem if you install them properly. You can proceed in following two ways to install three OS.

**Install OSX as it is** in a separate disk like normal installation. This will install the bootloader in the installation disk. Don't touch other disks during installation. Choose this disk as first bootable disk to boot OSX. While booting existing Windows and Linux system, choose your current boot disk as first boot disk. **NOTE**: Here disk means a separate hard disk, not a partition.

**Install OSX without bootloader** either in a separate disk or in a separate drive. Take care not to install the bootloader during installation. Search the internet for how to install OSX without bootloader. Then chainload the new OSX from existing bootloader. For that, you can add an entry manually in the existing `grub.cfg`. Alternatively you may log into existing Linux after OSX installation and use `grub2-mkconfig` tool to generate a new grub configuration for you.